# How to add a javascript script for use in GWT?

Tags: javascript, gwt

How do I add a script such as the jQuery library so it is available for use in GWT?  I know how to do JSNI, I just don't know how to make the jQuery library available to me so I can call it within JSNI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT can call any JS function or reference any JS variable on the page using [JSNI](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2008/07/getting-to-really-know-gwt-part-1-jsni.html), so as long as the JQuery script is also loaded on the page, you can call any JQuery code you want.

For example:

```
public native void callJQuery() /*-{
  $("p.neat").addClass("ohmy").show("slow");
}-*/;
```

Comment: please let me know if you ever figure out how to check and uncheck a radio button.

Comment: It's trivial to check/uncheck a radio button with regular GWT, why would you need to involve JQuery?

Answer (score 2):

They don't play well together, yet. The only way I know so far (correct me if I'm mistaken) is [GWTQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/). Give it a try ;)

**EDIT**

I re-explained my thoughts, hope it'll be more clear now

It is possible to call any desired custom JavaScript code, see Jason's answer.

I recommend using [GWTQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/), since it's successfull port of JQuery to Java-based GWT ecosystem and doesn't force you to use raw native JavaScript from Java code.

Comment: What do you mean by "they don't play well together"?

Comment: @Jason Hall -> You can do it like you posted, and by that I meant 'not play well'. I believe GWT should be focused on Java whenever possible. In other words, I prefer avoiding 'native JS hacks'. GWTQuery ports JQuery into GWT ecosystem really nicely I think. But this might just matter of my opinion, though.

Comment: That's fair, I agree that GWT apps should be Java-focused, that's the whole point of it after all, but your comment made it seem like it wasn't possible, or easy, to call JQuery from GWT, which isn't true. GWTQuery is a great alternative to calling JQuery in GWT, since it also avoids downloading both JQuery and GWT code.

Comment: I admint it might have looked confusing, so I edited my answer :)